# How to capture specific the character that was clicked on inside of a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selection

I'm looking for a way to capture the specific character (or character index in text) after the user clicks on it inside of a `contenteditable` div. Just to provide an example, please consider the following HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    Hello world
</div>
```

Suppose the user clicks right between "o" and "r", is there a way to know that, using JavaScript?

I'd imagine this would be covered by the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) but all my inquiry so far has produced me nothing.

I appreciate any help that you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the caret position, i have done a small snippet for you here. Have a look at it.
    `enter code here`http://codepen.io/19sthil80/pen/pEooVR

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do something like this. [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/CodeBroJohn/pen/PGooZY)

I have put an alert in so that you can see that it does indeed know what you clicked and if you click a space as in between Hello and World it knows as well.

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");
```

function clickify (e) {
    var arr = (typeof e.innerText !== 'undefined') ? e.innerText.split("") : e.textContent.split(""),
        max = arr.length,
        i = 0,
        template = "$c",
        result = "";

```
for (; i < max; i += 1) {
    result += template.replace("$c", arr[i]);
}

e.innerHTML = result;

}

clickify(div);
```